# Why this part of javascript code is executed?

Tags: javascript, php, javascript-objects

From my `index.php` file ,
when this line is executed :

```
<script src="javascript/GlobalQuran.js"></script>
```

then ,
`GlobalQuran.js` file is loaded .
When that js file is loaded then all the time the output shows me

```
"Oopss!!!, Something went wrong. please refresh your browser or try again."
```

I think this error message is produce from the below code which is the part of `GlobalQuran.js` file . Also I think , something wrong with `$.ajaxSetup`

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function() {
        layout.message("error", "Oopss!!!, Something went wrong. please refresh your browser or try again.");
        gq._gaqPush(["_trackEvent", "Error", "Oopss!!!, Something went wrong."])
    }
});
```

Can anyone please tell me why this portion of js code is executed ? I am pretty new in javascript

some part of GlobalQuran.js file code :

```
.
.
.
notCachedQuranID ? ($jsonp = $.support.cors ? "" : ".jsonp?callback=?", $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: !0,
            jsonpCallback: "quranData"
        }), $.getJSON(c + $jsonp, function(a) {
            gq._loadResponse(a, firstLoad)
        })) : (gq.layout.display(!0),
            gq.player.load("play"));
        return !1
    },
    _loadResponse: function(a, b) {
        if ("object" == typeof a) gq.data = $.extend(!0, gq.data, a), gq.data.loaded = !0;
        if (gq.search.isActive() && (gq.search.init(), gq.search.loading(!1), 0 < gq.search.totalRows()))
            for (var c in a.search.quran) {
                gq.search._positionStartVerse = c;
                break
            }
        if (a.languageSelected) gq.settings.selectedLanguage = a.languageSelected;
        b ? (gq.player.init(), !gq.quran.length() && "object" == typeof a && a.quran && ($.each(a.quran, function(a) {
            gq.quran.add(a)
        }), this.url.save()), gq.layout.displayStartup("object" ==
            typeof a)) : (gq.layout.display("object" == typeof a), gq.player.load("play"))
    },
    url: {
        load: function() {
            var a = window.location.hash,
                a = a.split("/"),
                b = a.length;
            if (2 < b && "search" == a["1"]) {
                if (gq.search.keyword() == a["2"] && 0 == gq.search.position()) return !1;
                gq.search._keyword = a["2"];
                gq.search._position = 0;
                return !0
            }
            if (2 < b && gq.settings.page != a["2"]) return gq.quran.reset(), selectedBy = a["1"].split("|"), $.each(selectedBy, function(a, b) {
                gq.quran.add(b)
            }), verse = a["2"].split(":"), 1 < verse.length ? (gq.settings.surah = Quran._fixSurahNum(parseInt(verse["0"])),
                gq.settings.ayah = Quran._fixAyahNum(gq.settings.surah, parseInt(verse["1"]))) : (verse = Quran.ayah.fromPage(a["2"]), gq.settings.surah = verse.surah, gq.settings.ayah = verse.ayah), gq.player.reset(), !0;
            return /^[0-9]+:?[0-9]*$/.test(a["1"]) ? (verse = a["1"].split(":"), 1 < verse.length ? (gq.settings.surah = Quran._fixSurahNum(parseInt(verse["0"])), gq.settings.ayah = Quran._fixAyahNum(gq.settings.surah, parseInt(verse["1"]))) : (verse = Quran.ayah.fromPage(a["1"]), gq.settings.surah = verse.surah, gq.settings.ayah = verse.ayah), gq.player.reset(),
                !0) : !1
        },
        save: function() {
            window.location.hash = "#!" + this.page()
        },
        hashless: function() {
            var a = window.location.href,
                b = a.indexOf(window.location.hash) || a.length;
            return a.substr(0, b)
        },
        page: function(a) {
            if (gq.search.isActive()) return "/search/" + gq.search.keyword();
            url = "/";
            (by = gq.quran.selectedString()) && (url += by + "/");
            return url += a || gq.settings.page
        },
        ayah: function(a, b) {
            if (gq.search.isActive()) return "/" + gq.settings.surah + ":" + gq.settings.ayah;
            url = "/";
            (by = gq.quran.selectedString()) && (url += by + "/");
            return url = a ? url +
                (gq.settings.surah + ":" + gq.settings.ayah) : url + (a + ":" + b)
        }
    },
    _cookieRead: function() {
        for (var a = "", b = document.cookie.split(";"), c = 0; c < b.length; c++) {
            for (var d = b[c];
                " " == d.charAt(0);) d = d.substring(1, d.length);
            0 == d.indexOf("settings=") && (a = d.substring(9, d.length))
        }
        a = $.parseJSON(a);
        $.extend(!0, this.settings, a);
        this.quran.init();
        this.recitor.init()
    },
    _cookieSave: function(a) {
        var b = "undefined" == typeof a,
            c = "",
            a = b ? this.settings : a;
        if (!b && null == a) return "{}";
        $.each(a, function(a, b) {
            c = "object" == typeof b || "array" == typeof b ?
                c + ('"' + a + '":' + gq._cookieSave(b) + ",") : "string" != typeof b ? c + ('"' + a + '":' + b + ",") : c + ('"' + a + '":"' + b + '",')
        });
        c = c.slice(0, -1);
        c = "{" + c + "}";
        if (b) a = new Date, a.setTime(a.getTime() + 31536E6), a = "; expires=" + a.toGMTString(), document.cookie = "settings=" + c + a + "; path=/";
        return c
    },
    googleAnalytics: function() {
        var a = document.createElement("script");
        a.type = "text/javascript";
        a.async = !0;
        a.src = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl" : "http://www") + ".google-analytics.com/ga.js";
        var b = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b);
        "undefined" == typeof _gaq && (_gaq = []);
        window._gaq = _gaq || [];
        this.googleAnalyticsID && _gaq.push(["b._setAccount", this.googleAnalyticsID]);
        _gaq.push(["_setAccount", this._gaID]);
        this._gaqPush(["_setSessionCookieTimeout", 36E7]);
        this._gaqPush(["_trackPageview"])
    },
    _gaqPush: function(a) {
        _gaq.push(a);
        this.googleAnalyticsID && (a[0] = "b." + a[0], _gaq.push(a))
    }
};
.
.
.
jQuery.fn.extend({
    scrollTo: function(a, b, c) {
        b = b || 0;
        return this.each(function() {
            var d = $(this).offset().top + b;
            $("html,body").animate({
                scrollTop: d
            }, a, c)
        })
    }
});
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function() {
        layout.message("error", "Oopss!!!, Something went wrong. please refresh your browser or try again.");
        gq._gaqPush(["_trackEvent", "Error", "Oopss!!!, Something went wrong."])
    }
});
```

**developer console error :**

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.muslimpoint.org/word-by-word-quran/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FQuran-GlobalQurancom%2F192781430775518&layout=button&show_faces=false&width=50&action=like&colorscheme=light&height=24'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
jqueryWithTools.pack.js:154 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.muslimpoint.org/word-by-word-quran/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.globalquran.com/all/page/1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
send @ jqueryWithTools.pack.js:154
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.muslimpoint.org/word-by-word-quran/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
apis.google.com/se/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&size=tall&annotation=none&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org%2Fword-by-word-quran%2F&gsrc=3p&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_US.bSaSBnJo3mU.O%2Fam%3DAQ%2Fd%3D1%2Fct%3Dzgms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOlScUDCc6laSimwcYo4nXUQAS-sQ%2Fm%3D__features__#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Conload&id=I0_1620128639790&_gfid=I0_1620128639790&parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org&pfname=&rpctoken=64765965:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
apis.google.com/se/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&size=tall&annotation=none&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org%2Fword-by-word-quran%2F&gsrc=3p&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_US.bSaSBnJo3mU.O%2Fam%3DAQ%2Fd%3D1%2Fct%3Dzgms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOlScUDCc6laSimwcYo4nXUQAS-sQ%2Fm%3D__features__#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Conload&id=I0_1620128639790&_gfid=I0_1620128639790&parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org&pfname=&rpctoken=64765965:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
apis.google.com/se/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&annotation=none&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org&url=http%3A%2F%2Fglobalquran.com%2F&gsrc=3p&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_US.bSaSBnJo3mU.O%2Fam%3DAQ%2Fd%3D1%2Fct%3Dzgms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOlScUDCc6laSimwcYo4nXUQAS-sQ%2Fm%3D__features__#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Conload&id=I1_1620128639801&_gfid=I1_1620128639801&parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org&pfname=&rpctoken=24294907:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
apis.google.com/se/0/_/+1/fastbutton?usegapi=1&annotation=none&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org&url=http%3A%2F%2Fglobalquran.com%2F&gsrc=3p&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.en_US.bSaSBnJo3mU.O%2Fam%3DAQ%2Fd%3D1%2Fct%3Dzgms%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOlScUDCc6laSimwcYo4nXUQAS-sQ%2Fm%3D__features__#_methods=onPlusOne%2C_ready%2C_close%2C_open%2C_resizeMe%2C_renderstart%2Concircled%2Cdrefresh%2Cerefresh%2Conload&id=I1_1620128639801&_gfid=I1_1620128639801&parent=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.muslimpoint.org&pfname=&rpctoken=24294907:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
(index):1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.muslimpoint.org/word-by-word-quran/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure favicon 'http://globalquran.com/favicon.ico'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
2GlobalQuran.js:3551 Uncaught TypeError: this.fullScreen is not a function
    at d (GlobalQuran.js:3551)
    at GlobalQuran.js:3607
    at handle (jqueryWithTools.pack.js:64)
    at q (jqueryWithTools.pack.js:58)
```

Comment: `$.ajaxSetup` sets up the default error handler for ajax call. If you want to see which ajax call contains error, you may need to provide the error handler to that ajax call. Or check the developer console of your browser

Comment: "Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.muslimpoint.org/word-by-word-quran/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.globalquran.com/all/page/1'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS." — This seems pretty clear

Comment: @franziga The question is now edited . Can you please checkout the question again . See the last portion/section of question . At the last of the question , developer console error is added . After checking, Can you please tell me how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: @Quentin So I think , I should make api server (api.globalquran.com/all/page/1)  http to https to solve this issue . This is the only way or is there any other way is exists ?

Comment: @Quentin But when I browse [api_link](https://api.globalquran.com/all/page/1) this link then my browser shows me the **connection is secure** that's means it contain https . So why I got this issue?

Answer (score 1):

According to jquery doc for [ajaxSetup](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

is to set the default value for ajax request, so the reason why the error handler/callback is called is because your ajax call throw an exception, i suggest you to check in network debug in your browser dev tools to see what wrong.